# Couldn't the Chimera Ant King be trapped in Knov's Nen dimension?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I enjoyed the anime a lot. Most of the time, no main character made bad decisions in fights or at progressing. However, in the Chimera Ants arc, wouldn't it be easier to trap the Chimera Ant King in one of the special rooms in Knov's Nen dimension? Are the rooms to weak to keep him in there?

They could just let him starve there. I know Knov was scared of the Chimera Ant's Nen, but he created those rooms before the battle, so one of the others could move the King there.

Comment: there is a spoiler markup for Q&As with spoilers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plan required the Hunters to somehow force the King to move into Knov's Nen rooms, which would be almost impossible. Knov creating a Nen portal close enough to the King and pulling him into the room is ruled out. As you mentioned, just coming into contact with Royal Guard Pouf's En caused him to suffer a mental breakdown.

The next option is for the other Hunters to move the King into Knov's rooms. The Hunters could not realistically hope to achieve that given the gap in power between Chairman Issac Netero and the King.<sup>1</sup> The Hunters were aware of this gap before entering the battle, so they wouldn't consider it.

The plan was also risky because the extent and nature of the King's powers are a big unknown. Even if they succeeded, what if the King's Nen could destroy Knov's Nen once he is inside the room, or if it could "hijack" Knov's Nen, analyze how it works and obtain the Master Key? (and so on) The Nen abilities in Hunterverse vary from compound interest to teleporting gorillas, so the King having some troublesome Nen abilities could not be ruled out.

---

<sup>1</sup> The anime confirmed this gap of power rather beautifully later when one of Netero's strongest attacks scores a direct hit on the King, who was *sitting on the ground*, but the King just wipes some blood off his cheek.

Comment: Well thats quite acceptable. But they also persuaded the King to follow Netero to an unknown place und he (coincidentaly) accepted it. So Netero really has to be shure that the rose bomb will work. Otherwise this part of the world (and maybe also the unknown part) wouldn't be safe.

Comment: @Phil It was actually the King who suggested that they fight elsewhere because Pitou was treating Komugi in the palace. It was convenient for Netero because he wanted to separate the King from the Royal Guards. We do not know what Netero and Zeno's original plan was to move the King to the testing ground. If it involved binding or capturing the King somehow, then yes, they could have moved him into Knov's room instead. But perhaps, they knew some limitations of Knov's Nen that we don't know. There is too much speculation already, or it could be the plain old "the author didn't think of it". :)